# Select the line of code that returns a vec4 with a float alpha value applied to a vec3 color*

Tags: glsl

Select the line of code that returns a `vec4` with a `float alpha` value applied to a `vec3 color*`

```
vec4(color, color + alpha)
vec4(color * alpha, alpha)
vec4(color + alpha, alpha)
vec4(color * alpha, color * alpha)
```

Comment: Can you please explain or provide me the guideline resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In glsl vectors can also be constructed from other vectors. See [Data Type (GLSL) - Vector constructors](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Data_Type_(GLSL)#Vector_constructors):

If you have a `vec3 color` and a `float alpha`, then you can construct a vector with 4 components:

```
vec4 color_rgba = vec4(color, alpha)
```

If a vector is multiplied by a floating-point value, then each component of the vector is multiplied by the floating-point value. See [GLSL Programming/Vector and Matrix Operations](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/Vector_and_Matrix_Operations):

```
color * alpha
```

is the same as

```
vec3(color.r * alpha, color.g * alpha, color.b * alpha)
```

---

This menas the answer to the question

> Select the line of code that returns a `vec4` with a `float alpha` value applied to a `vec3 color`

is:

```
vec4(color * alpha, alpha)
```

which is the same as

```
vec4(color.r * alpha, color.g * alpha, color.b * alpha, alpha)
```

or

```
vec4(color.rgb, 1.0) * alpha
```

---

The expressions

```
vec4(color, color + alpha)
vec4(color * alpha, color * alpha)
```

will gain an compile time error, because they are of the form `vec4( vec3(), vec3() )`.